# Angular cli build prod: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I try to build project with Angular CLI `ng build --prod` and I get this error:

> ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

**if I build with not `--prod` I do not get any error**

Full error:

```
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isParameterPropertyDeclaration (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:13445:88)
    at Object.filter (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:469:31)
    at transformClassMembers (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70813:20)
    at createClassDeclarationHeadWithoutDecorators (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70665:110)
    at visitClassDeclaration (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70584:19)
    at visitTypeScript (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70432:28)
    at visitorWorker (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70227:24)
    at sourceElementVisitorWorker (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70252:28)
    at saveStateAndInvoke (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70165:27)
    at sourceElementVisitor (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70237:20)
    at visitNodes (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67751:48)
    at Object.visitLexicalEnvironment (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67784:22)
    at visitSourceFile (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70521:53)
    at saveStateAndInvoke (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70165:27)
    at transformSourceFile (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70147:27)
    at transformSourceFileOrBundle (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70127:20)
```

Angular version:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.3
Node: 12.9.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 9.0.0-next.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.900.0-next.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.900.0-next.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.900.0-next.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.900.0-next.3
@angular-devkit/core               9.0.0-next.3
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.3
@angular/cdk                       8.1.4
@angular/cli                       8.3.3
@angular/http                      8.0.0-beta.10
@angular/material                  8.1.4
@angular/material-moment-adapter   8.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                   9.0.0-next.3
@schematics/angular                8.3.3
@schematics/update                 0.803.3
rxjs                               6.5.3
typescript                         3.6.3
webpack                            4.39.3
```

Thanks.

Comment: The comments reported on [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13172) may help you.

Comment: @Narm I saw this page but it doesn't help, tnx.

Comment: Add some code snippet to know where is the kind property that is trying to access, It would be very helpful to give us a anwser to you.

Comment: @DiegoBascans I added full error.

Comment: @YakirTsuberi I was informed by the Angular team that TypeScript 3.6.4 will be released ASAP to fix this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keep in mind now **TypeScript 3.6.4 is out.** Still, it's ok to read below what wasn't really working.

TypeScript `<= 3.6.3` presents this issue, [Handle parentless nodes in isParameterPropertyDeclaration](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33472).

If you install `3.7` (`dev` or the new `beta`), it will compile fine.

---

Note: if you receive an `ERROR` on building, regarding the TS version, just disable it via `tsconfig`.
For that use `disableTypeScriptVersionCheck`

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true
},
"compilerOptions": {
 ...
```

Follow the comment's chat if any other problem emerges.

Comment: I have encountered the same bug as the question, and upon doing an upgrade to TypeScript 3.7, I'm unable to build my angular project.  The error is, "ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.7.0-beta was found instead."

Comment: Thanks @LppEdd.  This does let me run my project build, however I'm still getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined" message when building an angular component.  Similar problem to the original question, where "ng build" works fine, but  "ng build --prod" throws this error.

Comment: @TimHolt that's strange. Imho I'd delete the node_modules folder, empty the package-lock, and then "npm install". Remember to close the terminal session too. The specific fix commit should have landed in beta too.

Comment: @TimHolt could you also link a pastebin with the full ERROR trace after?

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/RxNUL4US     This is after removing node_modules and re installing as you suggested.   The code mentioned (draggable-scroll.component.js) is from a module I'd recently added to the project.

Comment: @TimHolt could you **fix** the angular-devkit version to "0.803.8" (yours seems outdated) and angular/cli at "8.3.8"?

Comment: @TimHolt also angular-devkit/core to "8.3.8". You seems to have some dependencies to align to CLI version 8.3.8. Do not even try to go on CLI 8.3.9, it doesn't work correctly as of now with TS dev.

Comment: Ah yes those versions are a bit messed up.  I put them all to 8.3.9 and success!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200925/discussion-between-tim-holt-and-lppedd).

Comment: You're a friggin' life-saver.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This problem occurs by so many cases, one of the major reasons is installed version of @angular/cli is different to globally installed version of @angular/cli Make sure that both are same version. In other cases you have to update the devkit.

Please have a look on these threads, you will get an idea:

1. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13172
2. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13861

Answer (score 2):

Although the question specifically states `isParameterPropertyDeclaration` as the source of the error, this question is the only one linked by Google when searching for the following very similar error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/some_library/...
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
```

Since I couldn't find any good answer for the error above, I'm posting it here for reference.

If you're using a library affected by this error, you should upgrade your `@angular/cli` version to 8 or disable optimization in production mode (to disable optimization, change `projects.your_project_name.architect.build.configurations.production.optimization` from `true` to `false`).

If you're a library owner trying to fully support versions 6 and 7 of Angular, in the `tsconfig.json` of your library, set `compilerOptions.emitDecoratorMetadata` to `true` and recompile. Since now you're exporting all metadata from the decorators, Angular will do `.kind` of the exported metadata, fixing the problem where it was `undefined`.

Comment: compilerOptions.emitDecoratorMetadata to true resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to this when I was using ng-recaptcha v6.0.2 with angular v6.2.2

For me, the fix was to set buildOptimizer to false in angular.json

```
"configurations": {
    "development": {
        "buildOptimizer": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and solved it by updating my `typescript` dependency to the latest stable version.

In my case, I had version `3.7` and I fixed the issue by upgrading to `3.8`.