# Compile error when running ng build --prod in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting this error when running `ng build --prod` in angular.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-file/fesm2015/angular-file.js
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

I don't know whats causing this and how to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: looking like - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TypeScript <= 3.6.3** presents this issue

If you install **3.7** (dev or the new beta), it will compile fine.

Note: if you receive an `ERROR` on building, regarding the TS version, just disable it via `tsconfig`.
For that use `disableTypeScriptVersionCheck`

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true
},
"compilerOptions": {
 ...
```

**Edited:**

Change the angular-devkit version to "0.803.8" (yours seems outdated) and angular/cli at "8.3.8".

Hope this helps :)

[Reference] - [Angular cli build prod: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891605/angular-cli-build-prod-typeerror-cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined)

Comment: if I'm updating my typescript, i'm getting ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.7.4 was found instead.

Comment: Angular 8 does not support TypeScript versions beyond 3.5.3.

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked. Had to remove my node_modules folder and reinstall with updated cli and devkit