# Angular 8 :: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined, When making build for Production

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8

I am facing an issue, when trying to make production build with `ng build --prod` while `ng build and ng serve` running fine...

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-datetime-picker/fesm5/ngx-datetime-picker.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression
```

and here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "ubold-angular-vertical",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "7.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.2.1",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.2.0",
    "@iplab/ngx-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "angular-archwizard": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-query-builder": "0.5.1",
    "angularx-social-login": "^2.2.1",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "apexcharts": "^3.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "chartist": "^0.11.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "metismenujs": "^1.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.0.5",
    "ng-click-outside": "^4.0.0",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^5.0.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.2.4",
    "ngx-avatar": "^3.7.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "ngx-chartist": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^8.1.0",
    "ngx-datetime-picker": "3.0.0",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-editor": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^1.4.1",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^8.0.3",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.5.0",
    "ngx-timer": "^1.0.6",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.3.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.16.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.2"
  }
}
```

and `ng version` is

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.2
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.2
@angular-devkit/core              8.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.0.2
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.0.2
@angular/material                 7.3.2
@ngtools/webpack                  8.0.2
@schematics/angular               8.0.2
@schematics/update                0.800.2
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.4.2
webpack                           4.30.0
```

Tried this link
[Angular cli build prod: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891605/angular-cli-build-prod-typeerror-cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined)
but no success..
I tried much but no luck...
Please suggest....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue https://github.com/RenovoSolutions/ngx-datetimepicker/issues/88

For now downgrading `npm install ngx-datetime-picker@2.1.3 --save` appears to be the best solution. Not much action on that repo lately.

Comment: Wow.. Thanks @kavin  This worked for me too.. It means we need to install compatible version of package as per Angular version.
Could you please also suggest suitable version for ng-multiselect-dropdown and ng-multiselect-dropdown ?

Comment: Not sure i follow the ask, perhaps you could expand on this in it's own post.