# Angular 8 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined, When build my code for Production

Tags: angular, angular8

**Angular 8 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined, When build my code for Production**

```
  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
        at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:265:35)
        at checkNodeForDecorators (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:77:21)
        at visitNodes (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16514:30)
        at Object.forEachChild (/home/Project/adminPanel/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16740:24)
        at checkNodeForDecorators (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:68:31)
        at visitNode (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16505:24)
        at Object.forEachChild (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16635:21)
        at checkNodeForDecorators (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:68:31)
        at visitNode (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16505:24)
        at Object.forEachChild (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16692:24)
        at checkNodeForDecorators (/home/Project/newspod/adminPanel/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:68:31)
        at visitNode (/home/ Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16505:24)
        at Object.forEachChild (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16703:24)
        at checkNodeForDecorators (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:68:31)
        at visitNode (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16505:24)
        at Object.forEachChild (/home/Project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16599:21)
```

I am using this command to build

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party library like editor or anything which is not written on `angular`?

Comment: Does this answer you question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891605/angular-cli-build-prod-typeerror-cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined

Comment: yes, S Rana, I am using CKEditor on angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved It by Just changing my ngx-toastr version Related to anguler
Please compare ngx-toastr module version with Anguler

Refer this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr

Answer (score 3):

Update angular dev kit to latest. Follow the below links to do it.

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4-angular/issues/78#issuecomment-565803253
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Comment: I Removed Ck Editor from my app & then i was trying but same error occurring, & i have also tried npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular this command but after that another error occuring.

Comment: i am getting this error when updating build-angular version.

main.8dc4e75d93973b2ae58f.js:1 ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError[l -> t]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[l -> t]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for t!

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue and resoved by change the buildOptimizer: false in angular.json file.

**Just change**

```
buildOptimizer: true
```

**To**

```
buildOptimizer: false
```

worked for me

Comment: Before you paste this in even more locations, please take the time to read [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).

Answer (score 1):

Update your **typescript** version to **3.8.3** .

OR

Change **disableTypeScriptVersionCheck** in **tsconfig.json** file.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer But I also tried those types of things But it can not Working.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs by so many cases, one of the major reasons is installed version of @angular/cli is different to globally installed version of @angular/cli Make sure that both are same version. In other cases you have to update the devkit.

Please have a look on these threads, you will get an idea:

1. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13172
2. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13861
3. [Angular cli build prod: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891605/angular-cli-build-prod-typeerror-cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined)