# ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-select2/fesm5/ng-select2.js Module build failed, TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular8

**In previous system worked properly but when clone the project in new system so now i am getting this errors.**

**I have also tried to change(downgrade) "ng-select2": "^1.1.2", to "ng-select2": "1.1.2"**

**i am trying to solve and make build from 2 days but getting same issue no solution

anyone can help?
but getting same errors.**

**When i make build run command ( ng build --prod ) get this errors**

Angular CLI: 8.0.6

Node: 10.16.0

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 8.0.3

**dependencies**

..............

"ng-select2": "^1.1.2",

"ng-select2-component": "^7.1.5",

**Packages:**

@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.6

@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.6

@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.6

@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.6

@angular-devkit/core              8.0.6

@angular-devkit/schematics        8.0.6

@angular/animations               8.2.14

@angular/cli                      8.0.6

@angular/platform-browser         8.2.14

@ngtools/webpack                  8.0.6

@schematics/angular               8.0.6

@schematics/update                0.800.6

rxjs                              6.4.0

typescript                        3.4.5

webpack                           4.30.0

**Complete Errors:**

ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-select2/fesm5/ng-select2.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:265:35)
at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:77:21)
at visitNodes (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16514:30)
at Object.forEachChild (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16740:24)
at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
at visitNode (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16505:24)
at Object.forEachChild (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16635:21)
at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
at visitNode (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16505:24)
at Object.forEachChild (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16692:24)
at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
at visitNode (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16505:24)
at Object.forEachChild (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16703:24)
at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
at visitNode (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16505:24)
at Object.forEachChild (E:\xampp\htdocs\duski\duskifrontend\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16599:21)

Comment: Is it different to those questions?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63029367/angular-8-typeerror-cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined-when-build-my-c
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891605/angular-cli-build-prod-typeerror-cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined

Comment: Yes different from those questions

Comment: Have you tried updating your dependencies? One of the answers to these questions says that an old typescript version (like yours) was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find solution of this errors.

solved by change the buildOptimizer: fale in angular.json file.

**Just Change**

```
buildOptimizer: true
```

**To**

```
buildOptimizer: fale
```

worked for me

Comment: Before you paste this in even more locations, please take the time to read [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).